# Convert time and Date to 24hs

Tags: r

I have one dataset that has a column with 200k rows and every row presents different timestamps.
Example:

```
02/20/2019 01:30:00 PM  
15/02/2019 13:30:00
```

I have tried to use in R Studio:

```
dataset <-as.POSIXlt(dataset,format= "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

dataset <-as.POSIXlt(dataset,format= "%H:%M:%S")

dataset <-as.POSIXlt(dataset,format= "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S")
```

But the value changed for "01:30:00" what is considered "AM" or sometimes it brings "NA" as a result.

Do you know if there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

See the `parse_date_time()` function from the `lubridate` package:

```
dat <- c("02/20/2019 01:30:00 PM", "15/02/2019 13:30:00")

lubridate::parse_date_time(dat, orders = c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))

[1] "2019-02-20 13:30:00 UTC" "2019-02-15 13:30:00 UTC"
```

Note that if you have other combinations, such month/day/year with the 24 hour clock time, you'll have to add that specification in the `orders` argument:

```
dat2 <- c("20/02/2019 01:30:00 PM", "15/02/2019 13:30:00")

lubridate::parse_date_time(dat2, orders = c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")) # Wrong
[1] "2019-02-20 01:30:00 UTC" "2019-02-15 13:30:00 UTC"

lubridate::parse_date_time(dat2, orders = c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")) # Right
[1] "2019-02-20 13:30:00 UTC" "2019-02-15 13:30:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Yes, I am getting the same result. some rows with NA and others with correct format

Comment: You need to add further specifications in the `orders` argument, but unless you provide more examples of cases getting turned to NA, I cannot help you any more.